# Converting a string with date in US format to UK format

Tags: excel, regex, vba, string, date

I am trying to convert a string, which has a date in US format into UK format.

The following code seems to be hit or miss when it comes to a date that is single digits for both the day and the month:

```vb
X = 3

Do While strTimeStamp = 0
    If InStr(WS2.Cells(lRow, lCol), "TIMESTAMP") <> 0 Then
        strHPCStats = Split(WS2.Cells(lRow, lCol), " ")
        'strHPCStats(X) = Mid(strHPCStats(X), 4, 6)
        re.Pattern = "^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$"
        strHPCStats(X) = re.Replace(strHPCStats(X), "$3/$2/$1")
        strHPCStats(X) = Format$(strHPCStats(X), "dd/mmm/yyyy")
        strTimeStamp = strHPCStats(X)
        WS2.Cells(lRow, lCol).EntireRow.Delete
        lRow = lRow - 1
    Else
        WS2.Cells(lRow, lCol).EntireRow.Delete
        lRow = lRow - 1
        
    End If
    lRow = lRow + 1
Loop
```

The typical string:

```
4:19:17 (application) TIMESTAMP 3/13/2022
```

The string where it is having trouble:

```
5:36:32 (cameo) TIMESTAMP 4/1/2022
```

Comment: Does it work with 2 digits in month and day?

Comment: it seems to work on the first string provided but just doesn't want to know on the second

Comment: Does the same date come out? or do you get any errors?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav it seems to be hit and miss and i really struggle to understand RegEx. when either the day OR month has 2 digits it seems to work as expected but when both the day and month are single digits it goes to s***

Answer (score 1):

`d{2}` will look for exactly 2 digits, so if your date has a month (or day) with only 1 digit, the regex doesn't match.

If you want to specify 1 or 2 digits, you can for example use `d{1,2}`, so the statement would be

```
e.Pattern = "^(\d{1,2})(\d{1,2})(\d{4})$"
```

Details: [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Comment: Hi @funthomas, that was my thinking, but the OP said the 1st one works.  How is that?  Many thanks

Comment: I did this tweak but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use regular expressions, given your expected data.
Just look for two slashes in a space-separated string:

```
Function us2ukDate(S As String) As Date
    Dim v, w, x
    
v = Split(S, " ")
For Each w In v
    If (Len(w) - Len(Replace(w, "/", ""))) = 2 Then
        x = Split(w, "/")
        us2ukDate = DateSerial(x(2), x(0), x(1))
        Exit Function
    End If
Next w
    
End Function
```

***testing example***
[image]

If, instead of just returning the date, you want to change the format within the string, you could do something like:

```
Sub convertStrings()
 Const d1 = "4:19:17 (application) TIMESTAMP 3/13/2022"
 Const d2 = "5:36:32 (cameo) TIMESTAMP 4/1/2022"
 
Dim sParts

sParts = Split(d1, " ")
sParts(UBound(sParts)) = Format(us2ukDate(sParts(UBound(sParts))), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
Debug.Print Join(sParts, " ")

sParts = Split(d2, " ")
sParts(UBound(sParts)) = Format(us2ukDate(sParts(UBound(sParts))), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
Debug.Print Join(sParts, " ")

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers Ron for your answer. what does the Const do when adding a string ?

Comment: @madmiddle Should be `Const d1 as String = "..."` in which case it declares `d1` as a String with a defined content.   As is, it declares `d1` as a Variant, but for this small example, it's irrelevant.  It is good practice to always declare your variables. You can enforce this by `Tools/Options/Editor/Code Settings` and selecting `Require Variable Declaration`. This will place `OPTION EXPLICIT` at the top of each inserted module. This will be extremely useful in catching typos, variables of the incorrect type, etc.